# Am I using MySQLi UPDATE the right way?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, pdo

I have two tables in my database namely **tutors** and **students** with the following structure:

```
tutors table
+------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|tutor_id    |tutor_avail_credits |entry_time           |
+------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|    20      |      300           | 2017-01-22 11:53:10 |
+------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|    13      |      200           | 2017-01-24 13:58:45 |
+------------+--------------------+---------------------+

 students table
+------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|student_id    |student_credits   |entry_time           |
+------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|    20      |      50            | 2017-01-24 12:23:10 |
+------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|    13      |      100           | 2017-01-24 15:58:45 |
+------------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

I have a PHP script that allow students to reserve a tutor for a tutoring session that will run for minutes equivalent to student's credits. The way I had intended it to work was that, I run a query to fetch rows for the top most tutor(earliest since the list is sorted according to time)

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tutors 
             WHERE (tutor_avail_credits > 0 ) 
           ORDER BY entry_time ASC LIMIT 1 ";
```

If a student submits a form to reserve the top most tutor, his/her credits should be subtracted from the tutors credits until the tutor is fully reserved. Each time a reservation occurs **tutor_avail_credits** field should be updated until it's 0. So I have this code.

```
       <?php

         //Check if reserve button press
        if(isset($_POST['reserve'])){

           //Some code here.........

        if($student_credits < $tutor_avail_credits){
            $tutor_avail_credits = $tutor_avail_credits - $student_credits;
            //Update table field. 
            $update = "UPDATE tutors 
                       SET  tutors_avail_credits = '$tutors_avail_credits'
                       WHERE tutor_id = '$tutor_id'"
            }
           //Code continues.....
           ?>
```

Now the problem is that the field **tutor_avail_credits** will be accessed by multiple users at the same time, won't this cause some problems? if so, is it possible for me to have additional column in tutors table where I can set a flag after running a `SELECT` query so that it will be used as a condition allowing other users to select tutors which are currently not selected.Here is the query.

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tutors 
             WHERE (tutor_avail_credits > 0 AND status ='available') 
           ORDER BY entry_time ASC ";
```

Please I am a beginner point me in the right direction.

Comment: you might want to check this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for such a great advice, I will change my code as per the requirement.

Comment: @Gonzalo.-I am looking at it now, will keep you posted of my progress.Thank you